# magento installation error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO）

Tags: database

I want to install magento and I run the command below,

```
php bin/magento setup:install  --cleanup-database 
--base-url=“http://**.***.**.*/var/www/html/magento/“ 
--db-host=“database-1.************.***********-3.rds.amazonaws.com” 
--db-name=“magento2” 
--db-user=“admin” 
--db-password=“*********” 
--admin-firstname=“****” 
--admin-lastname=“*********” 
--admin-email=“************@gmail.com” 
--admin-user=“admin” 
--admin-password=“********” 
--language=“ja_JP” 
--currency=“JPY” 
--timezone=“Asia/Tokyo” 
--use-rewrites=“1”
```

Then I got an error,

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
In InstallCommand.php line 282:
  Parameter validation failed
```

As a test, I tried just the first command below,

```
php bin/magento setup:install  --cleanup-database
```

also I got the same error,

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
In InstallCommand.php line 282:
  Parameter validation failed
```

I think I have a problem on my database(MySql) but I'm not sure.

I am use RDS for database and running the commands on EC2.

Please help me!

Comment: are you sure my sql user name is admin or root? i think your SQL username is root.

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/yourprojecturl/pub" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="yourdatabasename" --db-user="root" --db-password="yoursqlpassword" --admin-firstname="magento" --admin-lastname="dev" --admin-email="test@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine="elasticsearch7" --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port="9200"
```

Comment: thank you for your anser

Comment: but I got the same error

Comment: you can run the above commands with db-password.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the database has any **password** set for the **root** user.

I think, in your case, the **password** is currently **blank**.

To check so, you can connect to the server via SSH and run the following command:

```
mysql -h {hostname} -u {username} -p
```

Provide the value of password. If it connects to the database, use the same password for the database while installing Magento.

If not, probably you need to change the database user's password first, then you can install your Magento.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I successfully connected to the database.

Comment: but I still can't install the magento.
I got the same error.
'''
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

In InstallCommand.php line 282:
                               
  Parameter validation failed  
'''

Comment: as I said on the first post, 
even the first command like below gives me the error.
'''
 php bin/magento setup:install
'''
Do you have any clue for it??

Comment: I couldn't understand how are you getting error for 'root'@'localhost' while you are using *db-host* as *database-1.************.***********-3.rds.amazonaws.com* and db user as **admin**.

Comment: Hi Mohit Kumar Arora,
Thank you for your answer.
I'm using rds as a database and there is no root user when i check.

Comment: ```
+--------------------+-----------+ 
| User                            |      Host     | 
+--------------------+-----------+ 
| admin         |  %     | 
| rds_superuser_role   |  %    |
 | mysql.infoschema    |  localhost  | 
| mysql.session        |  localhost  | 
| mysql.sys          | localhost  | 
| rdsadmin          | localhost  | 
+--------------------+-----------+ 
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
when I run your command with my db-password, i got an error like attached file...
[image]